# Avoid deallocation due to variable scope?

Tags: c++, object, memory-management

I need to achieve the following thing :

1. Create a variable anywhere in code, without using new ;
2. Anytime, keep a handler to this variable and ensure it'll never be deallocated ;

The goal is to create a tree in which you can add nodes with, as extra memory cost, nothing more than a pointer.

The problem is that I do not know how to do point 2, since variables are deallocated upon leaving a function if not using new.

Example with class A :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    int value;
    std::vector<const A*> sub_blocks;
public:
    A(int v)
    {
        value = v;
        sub_blocks = std::vector<const A*>();
    };

    A(std::vector<const A*> subs)
    {
        sub_blocks = subs;
    };
    A merge(const A & b, const A & c, const A & d);

    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & o, const A & si) {
        if (si.sub_blocks.empty()) { return o << si.value; }
        for (auto it = si.sub_blocks.begin(); it != si.sub_blocks.end(); it++)
        {
            o << (*it)->value;
        }
        return o;
    }
};

A A::merge(const A & b, const A & c, const A & d)
{
    std::vector<const A*> toReturn;
    toReturn.push_back(this);
    toReturn.push_back(&b);
    toReturn.push_back(&c);
    toReturn.push_back(&d);
    return A(toReturn);
}

A func1()
{
    A vA = A(3);
    A vB = A(4);
    A vC = A(1);
    A vD = A(5);

    A vE = vA.merge(vB, vC, vD);
    std::cout << vE << std::endl;
    return vE;
}

int main()
{
    A vOutside = func1();
    std::cout << vOutside << std::endl;
};
```

The output is `3415` and `????`. I'd like to have `3415` `3415`.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : The code [with unique_ptr](https://tio.run/##pVPbatwwEH2WvmJKIci5LA1tX7yOQWnyXOgPLLKs3YjYkmtJhlD227cj2Y432yy09MHgM5ejozMj2XU3shFmdzh81EY2oVZQDEp625d0iWjrfK9EexxrVWv7l5JS7HcOOP1FiTYeBtEEtabE@TrPR6oi/Qejfwa16XxfSGucB16W4EK1qRorn92adqFqtMwp4SyjBOlI4oI7@IR8ZCnFyF@xswz79pEvCTshHf6HFD9KBqtrEHW9MbZWbKqASxCxhEOr@t0SvoDqGhYgj0GNDZRse61MPaqYDMec7VQvoqKCnWaOKZzOIN5Ob4E5vVrutVJt519YhmnolQ@9AQtFgQ2rcVSADpGt7YGJ4C1oH514w1CpnTZ475j7cJpEyWPq6goNTg6TdAC71D67Ked9iIMgs4A0FzSRJgt5nr/rYlypo5O64J42lZDP7NxwmMjQyT2lPHL@i//xKA7e/kgC74CnMc949SrPP2n3fuaiOhOXZ@Jx6LMhc3oSvw1G3rJJ1MAh6vk8LtVwn9CXCX1L6HZCDwl9TduE8DFuOV@NPgz311iO30M2v05pg4@TwsK4EDGE02wWWcNjEhRfTyviCkyKvgfvdB0f0aT0D8a54i3vfn04/AY), still having the same output?

[Code1](https://tio.run/##fVNRa6QwEH42v2JKoUS7lS13fVG7kF77fHCvpRSN2W2oa8QkHuXY3743E5Vtu@0KojPf5JsvXyay665kU7ab/f5ct7LxtYJiUNKZfsUOGW2s61W5fZ@zrpSv7xOt@rtiDNmsBcH@sUi3DhIYysYruAWEATOPN0t8nnIWWVdn2dirkKa1DkSyAuur56ox8tXmrPNVo2XGIsGJa4hZhLRRYHxcPiHpgDzRYQlmvmTlMdbtckZM37a1x/TLY3qsG7kiAVvVbxQXcAHVAugjx08dU6t1r1Vbj4Im/xAznepL6l3wz8gCJj0YWB0DidFr4FanBw2p2nbujccIQ6@c71swUBS4IJ2F57DDlWvTAy@9M6AdCf9AUqmNbtEVws4@g6h6hC4v0ZLgSRR6JDzRjqyMqMHcnexgZK4AkWXfe0Ij8bX5zvwJXMg0/6adty/PFY4Yp8ERPHEv2sbxqZLqNCxPw3WAp00JPtdhckdbW/tWXvOwCQGDQEcF/xGHMRjuQvRzin6F6HqK7kN0EyYCwwcaWpGOLg13CyzH9z6e74M03pHVWEiHSik8juagbHgIgug@bEs6w0nRb@@srumiTUqPGOeKj7y7fL//Dw), working but allocating twice `vA, vB, vC, vD`, [code2](https://tio.run/##fVNda@MwEHy2fsUeB0V2U5PS64vtC6gfzwf3WkqxZSUVdSxjST6Okt@e7so2aZs2BmPv7mh2NFrJrruQTdlu9vufupWNrxUUg5LO9Ct2yGhjXa/K7fucdaV8eZ9o1b8VY8hmLQj2yiLdOkhgKBuv4DdgGTDzcL3E5zFnkXV1lo29Cmla60AkK7C@eqoaI19szjpfNVpmLBKcuIaYRUgbBcaH5SOSDsgTHZZg5ktWHiNulzNi@ratPaZfHtMjbuSKBGxVv1FcwBlUC6CPHD91TK3WvVZtPQqa/MOa6VRfUu@Cf64sYNKDgdUxkBi9Bm51etCQqm3n/vMYy9Ar5/sWDBQFLkhn4TnscOXa9MBL7wxoR8I/kFRqo1t0hWo/PhdR9Vg6P0dLgidR6JHwRDuyMqIGc3eyg5G5AkSWfe8JjcTX5jvzN3Ah0/ybdt4@P1U4YpwGh7tnbWMQPAk/8QnkWUW46jRGEkaextSEqQNm2qrgMxiTO9rw2rfykoetCRgE@iz4VRyGY7gJ0a8pug3R5RTdheg6zAmG9zTKIh29G24WCMf3Lp5viTTe0QEgkI6aUnhIzUHZcB8E0S3ZlnSyk6I/3lld0/WblB4xzoiPvLt8v38D), not working but without extra allocation.

Comment: Store objects in your map by value.

Comment: By doing so you have an extra cost, because you'll have both your value + the value in the map for a few time. I can't afford this sadly.

Comment: Then store then with a shaped pointer, a unique pointer, something. You have to allocate them somewhere, they can't be on your stack.

Comment: What's the problem with using `new`?

Comment: The idea is to use the tree structure as a template parameter without code rewriting : new is never used in "core" code. The only place where I could use new is in merge, but it means extra memory cost. The answer is probably the one Matthieu Brucher gave with the unique_ptr ; I'm trying to code it on class A and will post the solution if it works.

Comment: You using a `std::vector`.  The default allocator used by `std::vector` uses operator `new`.    You're also adding pointers to the vector, and they point at objects that go out of scope, so any subsequent usage of those pointers from the vector has undefined behaviour.   In any event, if you don't want lifetime of an object to be limited by scope, the object either needs to be a global (at file scope, or a static) or dynamically allocated (e.g. using operator `new`).   Or it needs to be contained somehow in an object that is global or dynamically allocated.

Comment: @Peter Exactly ; ideal case is your last sentence "it needs to be contained somehow in an object that is global or dynamically allocated". It looks like "unique_ptr" is doing the job since, following documentation `std::unique_ptr is a smart pointer that owns and manages another object through a pointer and disposes of that object when the unique_ptr goes out of scope`, which, from what I understand, means that while the unique_ptr is not out of scope, the object is still alive.

Comment: Ok I tried the code in main post EDIT, but I'm still having the same output with undefined behaviour. Am I mistaken on unique_ptr usage/goal?

Comment: When the program execution goes outside of func1() scope, vB, vC, vD will be destroyed and the vector contains invalid pointers => program crashes.

Comment: @tunglt this is what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: By default, the deallocator for `std::unique_ptr` also assumes the object is created with operator `new`, and may be released with operator `delete`.      If you're using a `std::unique_ptr` to ensure your object continues to exist,  your problem comes back to managing the lifetime of the `unique_ptr`.   The problem is still the same - you would just need the lifetime of `unique_ptr` to be independent of scope, rather than the object it manages.

Answer (score 3):

If you impose artificial constraints like "without using new", you should have a good understanding of C++. It seems you trip on some of the basics.

Let's start with the first part of your goal: "Create a variable anywhere in code, without using new ;". In C++, variables aren't created with `new`. They're created by declarations. `new` creates unnamed objects and returns a pointer to this object.

You do have a second goal which makes life easier. "ensure it'll never be deallocated". In C++, you should choose how to store the pointer returned by `new`. Store it in a regular (non-smart) pointer and don't call `delete`, and you'll be certain that the object is never deallocated.

As you correctly figured out, in C++ not all objects are created by `new`. Ordinary variable declarations inside functions create local variables, whose objects have a lifetime which ends when the function returns. That is unavoidable.

You *can* have variables inside functions which survive the return of those function; these are declared with `static`. Their lifetime is to the end of the program. But it looks like you wouldn't be helped by them; you get the same variable every time the function is called. And your tree obviously has more than one node. That's really no surprise. Like global objects, the memory for `static` objects can be allocated at program start-up. Both have so-called *static storage duration*, and take a finite amount of storage.

So, in conclusion you can't avoid `new`. You can hide it, though. And you probably should. Whether you use `std::vector<A>` or `std::list<A>`, each A object in the container is eventually created by `new`.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, tho, I'm a bit surprised. I mean, what if the object `vA` contains more than just one `int`. Let's imagine the size of `vA` is almost the size of the available memory, the only solution would be to use `new(vA)` which means you'll have to ensure you have at least twice the size `vA` available? This is a huge loss, isn't it?

Comment: @Spazz: I don't follow. If `vA` is an object (not a type), then `new (vA)` isn't even legal. Having said that, it's rather unlikely that your compiler supports having single objects that big anyway. Real-world big programs are big because they've got large collections of smaller objects.

Comment: Thanks ! Yeah I meant using `new (sizeof(vA))` but you're right, I'm in the case of a collection of smaller objects. My remark was stupid, forget about it. I guess I got the elements to deal with my tree, thanks people ;).

Comment: `new (sizeof(vA))` still doesn't make sense. The syntax is `new TYPE`. And the type is rather fundamental, because that is the type of object which `new` creates.

Comment: I was refering to the first function [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/).

Comment: @Spazz: That's `operator new`, not `new`. And why bring that up? It's typically only used behind the scenes, inside the C++ runtime library.

Comment: Because I'm trying code1 and code2 from original post to solve my problem, code1 is working since new is creating a new object, but code2 is undefined behaviour. I do not understand why to be honest, I'm getting a bit lost.